# Typsecript, dynamic object keys requires .toString(), why?

Tags: typescript

Take the below code interface and function:

```
interface Target {
  name: String;
  value: String;
}

export const validateInput = (target: Target) => {
  let valid: Object = {
    [target.name]: target.value,
  };
  console.log(valid);
};
```

Why does TS complain about [target.name]?

When I use

> [target.name.toString()]

Is works fine.

Comment: Please [edit] to put the error message in the text of the question.  The phrase "complain about" is not descriptive enough for this to be a [mre].  I can do it if you don't mind; let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object keys should be of [the primitive `string` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#the-primitives-string-number-and-boolean), not the `String` interface which describes the type of [the `String` wrapper *object*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String).  Note the difference in the case of the first character.

They are similar types but not the same.  Every `string` is a `String`, but not every `String` is a `string`.  It is [almost always a mistake to use the type named `String`; change it to `string` instead](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#number-string-boolean-symbol-and-object) and things will start working:

```
interface Target {
  name: string;
  value: string;
}

export const validateInput = (target: Target) => {
  let valid: Object = {
    [target.name]: target.value, // okay
  };
  console.log(valid);
};
```

The reason why `toString()` works is because the return type of that is the primitive `string` type.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpygcwmZBvAKGWRDgFsIAuZAZzClEwG4jkA3OAGwFcrb7GLAL4ECEAB4AHAPZRcCaSDrsuwACZxIASRCTuuALzIAFGAzYw1dFhwBKZAYB8+VpxwrO66gHkARgCsIBEMXYmIAbTMbMAA6UgoAXWooixiOHggAGmQAehzkaQBrOABPViEWYgUlaTcYzmlMY3T1W2EmIA)

Comment: Thanks. I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the object type `String` instead of `string`, and objects cannot be used as property keys. If you use `string`, it works:

```
interface Target {
  name: string;
  value: string;
}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBRgDN)